# Codeigniter redirect design fail

Tags: codeigniter, url

So i have and action button of edit and the fields to be edited on the same page using php. my problem is when i reload the edit button it will come back to the same page and add an additional url data.

```
function view_branch()
{
    $this->load->view('includes/a_header');
    $this->profile();
    $this->load->view('includes/a_footer');
    $this->load->view('admin/content/view_branch'); 
}
```

on top is my original method which views my html page view_branch

on the bottom is the button that reloads the page go to controller and finds the edit_branch method

```
$row[] = '<td class="w3-row" >
          <form method="post" class="w3-half"     
                action="edit_branch/'.$foo->BranchId.'" id="Edit">                        
                  <button class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>                      
                  </button>                                           
           </form>
          </td>';
```

so this button will go to my controller with the method name edit_branch that holds

```
public function edit_branch()
    {
        $this->view_branch();
}
```

what will happen is that it creates another url that would cause and error

two url edit_branch
http://localhost/GFC/index.php/Admin_Dashboard/edit_branch/edit_branch/CEB1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct the url differently using `site_url()`. Try this:

```
$row[] = '<td class="w3-row" >
            <form method="post" 
              class="w3-half"     
              action="' . site_url('admin_dashboard/edit_branch/'.$foo->BranchId) . '" 
              id="Edit">
            </form>
          </td>';
```

*Note: make sure the [URL Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) is loaded before using the `site_url()` function*